# Show that the first-differenced estimator is numerically identical to the fixed effects estimator

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

The problem here is to show that the first-differences estimator of the beta parameter in the model is numerically the same as the fixed-effects estimator of the same parameter.

Comment: You need to expand your question and provide more scope and details.